# How can I eliminate repeating this function as this list of clickable buttons grows?

Tags: jquery

Here is some newbie code that works but will bloat as the list grows. I'm looking for an approach that will eliminate repeating the click function bit every time a new input is created.

I'm creating a div as a button with a unique name, calling some values in a unique JSON file tied to that button, then storing the values in localStorage (the click will always call the same function).

This example deals with just three but the list could grow to dozens more.

```
<div style="display:none;">
<input class="hiddenWebInput" id="webImportInput1" type="text" value="fooList1.txt"  />
<input class="hiddenWebInput" id="webImportInput2" type="text" value="bar.txt"  />
<input class="hiddenWebInput" id="webImportInput3" type="text" value="foo.txt"  />
</div>

<script>


$("#webImport1").click(function() {

localStorage.setItem("picked", document.getElementById("webImportInput1").value);

getList();

});


$("#webImport2").click(function() {

localStorage.setItem("picked", document.getElementById("webImportInput2").value);

getList();

});


$("#webImport3").click(function() {

localStorage.setItem("picked", document.getElementById("webImportInput3").value);

getList();

});
```

The`getList()` is what I use to set other localStorage values and perform other stuff.

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div[id^="webImport"]').click(function() {
   var n = this.id.match(/\d+/g);
   localStorage.setItem("picked", $("#webImportInput"+n).val());
   getList();
})
```

Comment: Doesn't the `slice()` approach only work if the number is single-digit? I realise there's only three, currently, but the OP made a point of specifying this question was for 'if the list grows.'

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, in that case you are right, using regular expression is better.

Comment: This works. Nothing that uses the input class does. But, I'm still forced to repeat all of the numbered "webImports" and will break at 10 (?) The example with "$("input[id^webImport]") throws an error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id^webImport]

Comment: @user1452893 Try the updated answer. `[id^webImport]` should be `[id^="webImport"]`

Comment: @Raminson Was already there with no joy. Fails if it deals with input. OK with verbose IDs. Yikes! Conditional slice, maybe? Workaround for When slice needs to deal with larger numbers? Just a thought.

Comment: @user1452893 What type of element are `#webImport1` and `#webImport2` elements? I don't think you want to bind the click to `hiddenWebInput` elements, Am I wrong?

Comment: @Raminson Divs that act as buttons: <div style="width:100%; float: left; clear:left; margin: 0px 10px 0 0;" id="webImport4" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="d" data-icon="arrow-down" >Button1</div>

Comment: @user1452893 The problem lies here, you should select the div elements, try the updated answer.

Comment: @Raminson Precisely! Tried same as soon as your raised the bind issue  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the original question said "I'm creating a div as a button with a unique name" but in hindsight should have included that in the example code too. So, learned something about posting plus got the solution. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts are:

```
$("input[id^=webImport]").click(function() {
    var num = this.id.match(/d+/);
    localStorage.setItem("picked", document.getElementById("webImportInput" + num).value);
    getList();
});
```

But, honestly, that was superseded by the fact that you have a `class` on the `input` elements, so:

```
$("input.hiddenWebInput").click(function() {
    var num = this.id.match(/d+/);
    localStorage.setItem("picked", document.getElementById("webImportInput" + num).value);
    getList();
});
```

And then refined slightly, to use jQuery, rather than mixing-and-matching between jQuery, and DOM, selection methods:

```
$("input.hiddenWebInput").click(function() {
    var num = this.id.match(/d+/);
    localStorage.setItem("picked", $("#webImportInput" + num).val());
    getList();
});
```

Comment: or just name an argument for the event and use `event.target`…

Comment: Why not use this.id directly? Rather than reconstructing the id using a Regex. And can't you go even further and get the element directly from this?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson, I'm not sure I understand your question; I've constructed the `id` within the click-handler simply because the `id` is of a different, though predictable, form. I'm not sure how to make that part more concise?

Comment: @DavidThomas So far, no joy with any of the examples. Nothing happening on click. Not even triggering an alert or console.log. Yikes! I'm using JQM if that has any bearing. Original posted code retested and still works.

Comment: Is JQM affecting your DOM at all? Where do my answers fail, because if the posted HTML is accurate I can't see why it's failing. =/

Comment: Me neither but will keep at it. Not getting any errors just not getting the trigger from the click.

Comment: @DavidThomas Nothing that uses input classes works. Named IDs do. But, $("input[id^webImport]") throws an error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id^webImport]

Comment: Ah, the id-based selector-fail was entirely my fault, I had a typo, it *should* have been `id^=webImport` (as in [Raminson's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11821174/82548), but I left out the (essential) `=` part. I'm fascinated that the class-selector fails though, there's no typo there (and I checked, after realising the other one).

Comment: Thank you for the help! The interactions definitely helped my learning. I was quite pleased when I pursued a fix when the bind issue was raised and it matched the expert's.

Answer (score 0):

if the functionality is all the same, you can bind the event using the class instead of id.

like

```
$('.hiddenWebInput').click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("picked", $(this).val());
});
```